# How to add Appbar Actions in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

In android, each fragment has override onCreateOptionsMenu, which has provided the possibility to add individual options menu in each fragment. How this can be made with flutter while changing pages from the drawer when the appbar is common to the app

Comment: so you want to change the app bar on each fragment? or want the same app bar on them?

Comment: i want the same app bar on each fragment just like android

Comment: If you want the same appbar with identical actions on every screen - you can create abstract class, where would be needed appbar. And extend this class for all your screens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add AppBar in every screen.

```
 class SDF extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SDFState createState() => _SDFState();
}

class _SDFState extends State<SDF> {
  int body = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("I Am AppBar"),
        actions: getActions(body),
      ),
      body: getBody(body), //here you can add your body
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
             RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              body = 0; 
            });

          },
          child: Text("Home"),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              body = 1;
            });

          },
          child: Text("Settings"),
        ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getBody(int body) {
    switch (body) {
      case 0:
        return Container(); // Home Screen

      case 1:
        return Container(); // Settings Screen
    }
  }

  getActions(int body) {
    switch (body) {
      case 0:
        return [
          Icon(Icons.settings),
          Icon(Icons.home),
        ]; // Home Screen

      case 1:
        return [
          Icon(Icons.home),
          Icon(Icons.settings),
        ]; // Settings Screen
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i also did like this, but i want to know is there a another way like android

Comment: did not understand exactly. Please brief what you want.

Comment: How do we add an onpressed or on taped function to perhaps go to  a different page after the action button is tapped

Answer (score 8):

The richness of flutter is that you does not have to write number of properties like html, css lots of stuff
the flutter provide simple way for that using one property such as below example

under the Scaffold just add this code

```
appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Action Demo"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // do something
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

When building the `AppBar` add `actions`. Do this within the `State` object of your page and use that state (which also controls your body) to control your actions creation. Use e.g. a list of `IconButton`s:

```
// We're withing the PageState here. e.g.
// class MyPageState extends State<MyStateObject> {

Widget createAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    actions: createAppBarActions()    
  );
}

List<Widget> createAppBarActions() {
  // use your app state here to create the actions you need
  // use if / else or switch / case for the states
  return [
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.share),
      onPressed : onSharePressed,
    ),
  ];
}

void onSharePressed() {
  // execute the action here
}
```

Don't forget to import `material` if you use the `Icons` package as above.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```